# Что нужно сделать, чтобы отправлять запрос через телефон?

Tags: flutter, dart

Всем привет, написал небольшое приложение на flutter, в эмуляторе все работает прекрасно, но когда я запустил его на телефоне, я не могу войти(авторизация), и ошибок не выкидывает, как я понял, запрос тупо не отправляется, что мне нужно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно добавить в файл AndroidManifest.xml эту строчку:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

над тегом

```
<application ...
```

Comment: Теперь мой файл AndroidManifest.xml (android/app/src/main) выглядит так -
`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.postterminal">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <application
        android:label="postterminal"
................................
</application>
</manifest>`
Однако, я по прежнему не могу войти

Comment: Я понял, что мне это помогло, но я использовал мобильный интернет, при переходе на Wi-Fi сразу заработало, подскажите, почему так? И что нужно сделать, чтобы работало через мобильный интернет

Comment: попробуйте добавить еще строчку <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
тут скорей всего нужно искать конкретные permissions для решения проблемы

Comment: К сожалению, это не помогло, но спасибо вам за ответ!